# zypper: no repositories defined

Tags: ubuntu, zypper

The environment is: Ubuntu 20 sub-system in win10.
When I run: `sudo zypper install -t pattern devel_C_C++`. It reported: `Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.`

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `zypper` instead of `apt`?

Comment: I want to install OpenFoam, the website is: https://openfoam.org/download/source/software-for-compilation/. It recommand `zypper`.

Comment: No, the command you use is for openSUSE, please use command for Ubuntu (`sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git ca-certificates flex libfl-dev bison zlib1g-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev libopenmpi-dev openmpi-bin gnuplot libreadline-dev libncurses-dev libxt-dev`)